# How can I limit the height of a window to a percent of the screen resolution using the MVVM pattern?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a window that is configured in this way:

```
<Window x:Class="Catalogo.Views.dlgGenerosContenidosAsignarView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="dlgGenerosAsignar"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
```

I want the window to adjust to its content, so I use `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`. But if the content is too big, it can outsize the screen, so I would like to limit the value of the `MaxHeight` attribute to the height of the screen.

How could I do this using the MVVM pattern?

I could use binding to a property in my ViewModel that uses the `System.Windows.SystemParameters` to get the height of the screen and set a property that binds to the View, but I think that the size of the window should be set in the View, not the ViewModel, so I would like to know if there is another solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of confusion around using the code behind, when following the MVVM methodology. This is really a perfect situation where you would want to use the code behind. As you correctly noticed, this is purely view related and should not be in the view model. It has no reason, or possible benefit from being in there.

So, if I were you, I'd add a handler to the `Window.Loaded` event, get your measurements and set the `Window.Height` to the desired `Height`:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Assuming that you want the Height to be 80% of the screen Height
    Height = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight * 0.8;
}
```